# Compatibility mode between phone and tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am so confused after reading "Screen Compatibility Mode" [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screen-compat-mode.html). First of all, I created two different sizes of the same image. Secondly, I created just one layout. Thirdly, I set 150dip to my image. Finally, I got correctly in my Galaxy SII(High Density) but I didn't get correctly when I emulate a Tablet 10"(Medium density). See the distance to the right border in both devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:text="DENSIDADE" />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:src="@drawable/mode_tapcolor"
    android:layout_width="150dip"
    android:layout_height="150dip" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Emulator of Tablet 10"]
[image: Samsung Galaxy SII]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create another folder **value-xlarge** in **res** to store dimension values. So the XML code should be:

**layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height"
    android:text="DENSIDADE" />

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/image1"
    android:src="@drawable/mode_tapcolor"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/default_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**values/dimens.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="default_width">75dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="default_height">75dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

**values-xlarge/dimens.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="default_width">150dip</dimen>
    <dimen name="default_height">150dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

So when apk is installed, it will use the right dimension values for the right device. The same goes for drawable, you can create drawable-xlarge to store images for tablet if you want.